# sql date days substraction with db2jcc

Tags: java, date, db2

I have an SQL, what tries to subtract days from a date value. This SQL must be working in Oracle and DB2 databases too, and I called it from Java with db2jcc 10.5.0.1 .
The call threw this Exception:

```
09:25:17 ERROR (out) com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][1083][10400][3.66.46] Illegal conversion: can not convert from "java.sql.Date" to "java.lang.Integer" ERRORCODE=-4474, SQLSTATE=null
09:25:17 ERROR (out)    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.dd.a(dd.java:725)
09:25:17 ERROR (out)    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.dd.a(dd.java:60)
09:25:17 ERROR (out)    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.dd.a(dd.java:94)
09:25:17 ERROR (out)    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gc.a(gc.java:585)
09:25:17 ERROR (out)    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gc.a(gc.java:1338)
09:25:17 ERROR (out)    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gc.a(gc.java:1314)
09:25:17 ERROR (out)    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.po.a(po.java:2426)
09:25:17 ERROR (out)    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.po.Fc(po.java:5722)
09:25:17 ERROR (out)    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.po.b(po.java:4078)
09:25:17 ERROR (out)    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.po.b(po.java:4536)
09:25:17 ERROR (out)    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.po.gc(po.java:739)
09:25:17 ERROR (out)    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.po.executeQuery(po.java:708)
```

I made the SQL and the java code simplier, but it still throws the Exception:

```
PreparedStatement pstmnt = connection.prepareStatement("select ? - 1 from dual");<br>
pstmnt.setDate(1, new Date(2013, 12, 07));<br>
ResultSet rs = pstmnt.executeQuery();<br>
```

It's strange for me, becuse this SQL still works:

    `SELECT TO_DATE('1979-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') -1 FROM dual`

Is it a common driver problem, or I missed something?

**EDIT:**

I use this date inside a TO_CHAR, like this:
    `SELECT TO_CHAR((CURRENT_TIMESTAMP -1 DAYS),'YYYY') FROM DUAL;`
This is not useable in Oracle.
I solved the problem in an other way, but I'm still interested in the answer.

Comment: I seem to remember writing my DB2 statements (it was a while ago now) as SELECT * FROM table where field=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP-1 days   Perhaps you need to add the 'days' in to your query too? (we used the db2jcc drivers as well)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I forgot some parameters from the question, and this is not usable for me.

Comment: I guess the next option would be to create a Date in your java code, manipulate the day there, and then pass it in. This way you don't need to worry about database specific implementations for date handling.

Comment: er, which version of DB2?  The AS/400 version doesn't have `dual`, that I'm aware of.  Additionally, most date/time functions I'm aware of tend to be vendor specific, in some small way, especially for date math.

Comment: I don't know which version was it, but I had dual.
It was tricky to find the way to modify the Date object in the context of query, but that was the solve. :) I think the real problem wasn't the subtraction, but using of the format parameter in the TO_CHAR with Date.
Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use interval unit names on date calculations.

***Example***:

```
current date + 1 YEAR 
current date + 3 YEARS + 2 MONTHS + 15 DAYS 
current time + 5 HOURS - 3 MINUTES + 10 SECONDS

CURRENT TIMESTAMP - MICROSECOND (current timestamp) MICROSECONDS
```

***Refer to***: [***DB2 Basics: Fun with Dates and Times***](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0211yip/0211yip3.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I forgot some parameters from the question, and this is not usable for me.